# Find sub-matrix containing the maximum number of elements consisting only of 1's

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, matrix

I am trying to get help on it here, originally posted first at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446920/find-sub-matrix-containing-the-maximum-number-of-elements-consisting-only-of-1s

Basically trying to get the max sub matrix that contains only 1's of a matrix that is filled with 0's and 1's.

I could figure out the max sub matrix, now I just need to find how to do so that the sub matrix is only 1's.

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-rectangle-binary-sub-matrix-1s/amp/

Comment: Do the rows and columns of the submatrix need to be contiguous, or can there be gaps?  Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Please don't re-post your question on multiple sites.